# Do I need GLSL Multipass Shading

Tags: opengl, glsl

Trying to better understand GLSL in realation to 'multipass shading'...

know that HLSL supports multipass shading as part of its language, so for example, a human skin shader in HLSL, has several passes in one 'pixel' shader.

How much of this can be accomplished in a single pass GLSL shader? i.e. can i just calculate all i need in one pass, i.e. diffuse,spec,sss,etc? or will I quickly hit limits that will push me to a multipass solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do in one pass. I've done some heavy GLSL shaders and never hit instruction limits yet.

BTW, in GL multi-pass rendering has next to nothing to do with GLSL, it's just a rendering of the same object several times with possible different shaders and polygon offsets.